# Interpolate/Resize ascii art in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, text, scipy

I want to resize some ascii art. Say it looks like this:

```
..K
.T.
.A.
```

I want to upscale it, by some number n, so it will look like this (n=2)

```
....KK
....KK
..TT..
..TT..
..AA..
..AA..
```

One way I thought about doing this was to convert the text into a matrix of their ascii values and use some interpolation function to resize the matrix, and convert it back to text to achieve the desired result, but I have not been able to find a function that will do that for me.

What is the easiest way to do this. If it makes it simpler, you can assume that n is always 4. (Because in my current situation this is the scale I need)

Comment: That's not really interpolating (which would give for example `...*#K` for the first line). It's just doubling every item, horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a file `test.txt` with following content:

```
..K
.T.
.A.
```

The following code will read the file and prodcue an output file `test_out.txt` which contains horizontally and vertically multiplied characters, depending what you specify for `N`:

```
N = 4

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open('test_out.txt', 'w') as out_f:
        for line in f:
            # Repeat characters N times horizontally
            output = "".join([N * c for c in line.strip()])

            # Repeat lines N times vertically
            for _ in range(N):
                out_f.write(output + '\n')
```

#### Output (test_out.txt) for N = 2:

```
....KK
....KK
..TT..
..TT..
..AA..
..AA..
```

#### Output (test_out.txt) for N = 4:

```
........KKKK
........KKKK
........KKKK
........KKKK
....TTTT....
....TTTT....
....TTTT....
....TTTT....
....AAAA....
....AAAA....
....AAAA....
....AAAA....
```